# proxy authentication selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I use java, selenium.
How can I authenticate a proxy with a login and password in chrome or firefox. The option with AutoIt or any extensions for browser does not fit,use proxy for the whole system is also not an option, since there is a simultaneous launch of multiple browsers with different proxies.
As I know, selenium doesn't provide tools for it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and the only way I managed it to work was using this extension - https://www.crx4chrome.com/crx/1446/.

Here is a code example. It's not JAVA but it should give you the idea

```
if (proxy.Credentials != null)
{
    proxyIpPort = $"{proxy.Address.Host}:{proxy.Address.Port}";
    var creds = proxy.Credentials as NetworkCredential;
    proxyLogin = creds?.UserName;
    proxyPassword = creds?.Password;
    options.AddExtension(Path.Combine(PathHelper.AssemblyDirectory, "Resources", "extension_2_0_0_0.crx"));
}
```

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
if (proxyLogin != null)
{
    driver.WaitForElement(By.Id("login"), "Proxy login").SendKeys(proxyLogin);
    driver.WaitForElement(By.Id("password"), "Proxy password").SendKeys(proxyPassword);
    driver.WaitForElement(By.Id("save"), "Proxy save").Click();
    driver.Close();
    driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.First());
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I already use, but this is not always work correctly for me